# How does static friction provide centripetal acceleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, centripetal-force

While reading about the motion of a car on a level road, I read that static friction provides centripetal acceleration? Please explain as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, the static frictional force between tyre & the road will act in the lateral direction normal to the direction of motion of car while taking a turn without slipping on the road.

The static friction between tyre & the road will provide the centripetal force to balance the centrifugal force $(mr\omega^2)$ only when a car takes a turn or moves on  a circular or curved path. This centripetal force prevents the wheels from sliding in lateral direction on the road.

Although, while taking a turn, the car is subject to a couple formed by centrifugal force & the centripetal force (provided by friction between tyre & road).